# Excel Index Match - Partial strings with Multiple Results

Tags: excel

I'm trying to tweak this piece of code I found in a sample spreadsheet online but I can't quite get my head around it.

The original spreadsheet basically does an INDEX/MATCH based on a user-defined lookup and lists the matches neatly in a concatenated list. The sample spreadsheet's output looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DyahB.png - Sample Excel Output (Note how there are no gaps between the first and second matches)

The underlying algorithm is:

`=IF(ISERROR(INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2)),"",INDEX($A$1:$B$8,SMALL(IF($A$1:$A$8=$E$1,ROW($A$1:$A$8)),ROW(1:1)),2))`

Now, I want the lookup to instead retrieve ***PARTIAL*** matches, and in addition, generate the outputs horizontally like so:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ShED0.png - Output is generated horizontally based on partial matches

I'm not sure how I would go about doing this. It seems like I would somehow try and change the IF condition to return true on partial matches but I can't get my head around it. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by "partial match" you mean text that **starts** with the value in `L1` then use this formula in `N1`

`=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$8,SMALL(IF(LEFT($H$2:$H$8,LEN($L$1))=$L$1,ROW($I$2:$I$8)-ROW($I$2)+1),COLUMNS($N1:N1))),"")`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>
 and copy across

For a match **anywhere** in the text you can use this version

`=IFERROR(INDEX($I$2:$I$8,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L$1,$H$2:$H$8)),ROW($I$2:$I$8)-ROW($I$2)+1),COLUMNS($N1:N1))),"")`

Neither formula is case-sensitive, although you can easily make the latter so by changing `SEARCH` to `FIND`

Use of `IFERROR` function means you don't need repetition for error handling - needs `Excel 2007` or later version

Answer (score 0):

Building on Barry's code a little, I needed to make a few tweaks for my own use (current project I have at work).

Tweaks I made:

1. Returning the cell that matches my search criteria in my index
2. Making the cell draggable in two dimensions so I could index multiple columns for specific information
3. Making the "nth" counter vertical instead of horizontal (as my application is a database of sorts, and each column is a separate entry. At the top of each column is 5 rows populated based on the search term [in my case, the store number])

The final result is:

`=IFERROR(INDEX(A$8:A$295,SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH('Store History'!$F$2,A$8:A$295)),ROW(A$8:A$295)-ROW(A$8)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")`

It is worth repeating that this is an array formula and needs to be entered using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

This is placed in cell A2 and is dragged both vertically and horizontally (horizontally in my case is ever expanding as I add more entries into my database).

My purpose for adding this comment (even though it is a long inactive thread) is to try and make this a more relevant search result on Google for "excel index match partial strings with multiple results" or variations of that. It took me hours of searching to find this solution, and it is extremely functional and elegant. My thanks to the OP and especially to Barry for his code!!

Comment: It is kind of unclear to me (granted, I do lack domain knowledge here) whether this is commentary on the other answer, an answer to the original question, or an answer to another, more general question. If it's the latter, posting a new question that clearly states the more general requirements and self-answering it would be the best action.

Comment: I didn't realize we were allowed to self-answer. I'll do that. Thank you!

Comment: @BaummitAugen I've posted a question and reply here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52193928/excel-return-multiple-partial-string-matches-in-arrays/)