# Index/Match with Multiple Criteria and Multiple Outputs

Tags: excel

How to add a second criteria to this excel formula?

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX($I$2:$I$8,
          SMALL(IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($L$1,$H$2:$H$8)),ROW($I$2:$I$8)-ROW($I$2)+1),
                COLUMNS($N1:N1))),
        "")
```

I need to use two criteria, one with a partial text search (not necessarily in the beginning) to generate multiple outputs.

[Input Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uaxnf.png)

[Output Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSDVm.png)

Comment: You cannot generate "multiple outputs" with a formula.  Please edit your question to show us your inputs and expected results.  The generic formula for multiple criteria when using `INDEX`/`MATCH` is `=INDEX(range,match(1,((multiple criteria)),0))`.  Cheers, Michal

Comment: Please explain a bit further maybe an example of what you’re trying to accomplish. What data do you need to look for? Hard to see from this formula.

Comment: Thank you both for getting back to me. I edited my original post to include a picture of the input and output sheets in my excel. The formula which I quoted, which I have not been able to get to work but which I think is a step in the right direction, comes from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31449440/excel-index-match-partial-strings-with-multiple-results/31453464

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with myself:

=INDEX(Table[Target],SMALL(IF(L$2=Table[InvestmentYear],IF((ISNUMBER(SEARCH($B$56,Table[Shareholders]))),ROW(Table[Target])-ROW(INDEX(Table[Target],1))+1)),ROWS($A$1:$A2)))

Would be great to hear any other thoughts on how to make it more clean.